# Inspecting element isnt enabled, execute isnt enabled as well

Tags: java, eclipse

I am doing my first java project using Eclipse.
Watching a video tutorial I get to the point to inspect element in my Scrapbook page. Right clicking on the editor this menu appears:

[image]

As you can see on the picture above I am not allowed to choose inspect option. Some help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse, add the break point where you want to inspect and run the project in debug mode (Debug As -> Java Application). While debugging the application, will hit break point. Select the variable or the expression that you want to inspect and press **ctrl+shift+i** or Right click -> inspect.